# How to customize a jquery table collapse script

Tags: jquery

I managed to get a table to collapse using this script. I am trying to figure out how to get only the first row to remain expanded while the remaining of the row stay collapsed.

At the moment my script has everything collapsed. I can't figure out how to specify having the first row expanded and the rest collapsed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$('.container tr:not(.header)').slideToggle(0, function(){});

$('.header').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').find('tr').slideToggle(0);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(10, function(){});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get what you want -- which is have the first table un-collapsed you could add an extra class to the first table and call it like so when the document is ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.first').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(0);
});
```

See this fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/g67AH/20

You can use the CSS `:not` and `:first-child` selectors. This will make sure that the `tr` elements collapsed are not the first child.

```
$('.header').click(function(){
   $(this).find('span').text(function(_, value){return value=='-'?'+':'-'});
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').find('tr:not(:first-child)').slideToggle(0);
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header:not(:first-child)').slideToggle(10, function(){});
});
```

Another option is to have a header row for your table like so :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
            <th>Header 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row1 column 1</td>
            <td>Row1 column 2</td>
            <td>Row1 column 3</td>
            <td>Row1 column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then all you need to do is call `.slideToggle()` on the `tbody` and your headers should stay put.

### See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g67AH/) for an example replicating both suggestions

Comment: That didnt do it, I made a fiddle of what my table currently looks like http://jsfiddle.net/g67AH/16/ not quite sure how to fit the code like you mentioned. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3403017 it looks like it is working... what row are you trying to leave shown? Do you want this row to always be shown after a collapse?

Comment: I would like to have the first header to be shown with it's data when you first load the page while having all other headers collapsed. I would like it to function like Jquery's Accordion example http://jqueryui.com/accordion/, the first header is shown with it's data and then you click on another header to show the additional data while collapsing the other headers.

Comment: @user3403017 ahh okay i gotcha... all i did was add a class to the first header calling it "first"... take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/g67AH/20/